# Want some help in Wix for making my site more interactive

Tags: web-development-server, velo

I have created a user generated site where users can upload files to the database but I also want the files to be downloadable for others.
Can I get some help on that?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple. You can connect the field with the file in the database to a button using a dataset and the button's connect panel. Depending on your use case, you might want to do this on a dynamic page.